# Create a custom component on top of Angular Material mat-select

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to create a custom component on top of angular material mat-select.
The custom component should support both reactive form and not a reactive form.

The custom component get inputs as:
 @Input() group: FormGroup; 
 @Input() controlName: string;

the custom component HTML

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="group">
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" [formControlName]="controlName">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

it works fine when I pass the group and the controlName
but when I want to use the same component without reactive form I get error: "formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in"

```
<!-- With Reactive Form -->
<app-custom-dropdown [group]="form" [controlName]="'foods'"></app-custom-dropdown>

<!-- Without Reactive Form -->
<app-custom-dropdown></app-custom-dropdown>
```

My Question is how I can support both cases when the custom component used
with reactive form and in other time without reactive form.

[stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8qgag?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html)

Comment: Why do you need it without reactive form? What is the use of the component ?

Comment: This custom component is a drop-down with closed os types that I use in a big project.
In the project we sometimes use   forms as template driven and and sometimes reactive form

Answer (score 1):

when you are using template form and calling your component like so

```
<app-custom-dropdown></app-custom-dropdown>
```

you do not pass formGroup, so in you `app-custom-dropdown`  component `@Input() group` will be undefined, which you are passing in template

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="group">
```

so here you need to add condition to not pass `group` if it's undefined

**UPDATE**
here is one of possible examples

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet='group ? reactive : template'>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #reactive>
  <mat-form-field [formGroup]="group">
    <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" [formControlName]="controlName">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #template>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: How do you this condition?

Comment: it depends how are you using formGroup in <mat-form-field> component

Comment: also you should remove formControlName and do templateRef stuff in your mat-form-field and mat-select components, which is a bit complicated

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8qgag-sttnkj I have update link here, please check again the previous version wasn't saved

Comment: I saw your solution and that how I did in my project I'm working on. The reason I don't like this solution is I have to maintenance two template.
But thanks for your help any way